# Can a bound be given to $\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\chi(a)\left(\frac{a^2-1}{p}\right)$, which is smaller than $p$, where $\chi$ is a dirichlet character?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, gauss-sums

Here $(\cdot)$ denotes the legendre symbol and $p$ be an odd prime number. All terms are of norm 1. So one bound is $p$. can one better bound be given to the sum?

Comment: Have you looked at the Polya-Vinogradov bound?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: It will be helpful if you please explain your answer.

Comment: I didn't answer. I questioned. I asked you whether you have looked at the Polya-Vinogradov bound. Have you?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I have tried using Polya Vinogradov bound but I was unable to find one good bound because of the Legendre symbol.